# Include jquery on dokuwiki page

Tags: dokuwiki

I'm trying to add a html/javascript page, into our dokuwiki.

I saw the  tag works fine for the body of the page and to run simple javascript.(alert())
But our javascript works with Jquery, and I don't know how to include it to my new dokuwiki page.

Is there any way to do that  ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

DokuWiki already includes jQuery - no need to load it yourself.

Comment: I think the user was asking HOW to use jQuery within a DokuWiki page, possibly through the WYSIWYG?  Do they use the 'html','code', or 'file' tags or is there some other formatting tag.  Is there a special editor?